# Multiple .Include in Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, .net-core

At first, here what I have:

4 Classes have some **relations** between them as:

**Project** has many Bridges.

**Bridge** has many Foundations.

**Foundation** has many **PierCap**s and many **PierColumn**s.

**Project.cs**:

```
public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        Bridges = new HashSet<Bridge>();

        StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        EndDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    // Fields
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    // Calculated Fields
    public int BridgeCount => Bridges.Count;
    public int PierFoundationCount = 0;
    public int PierCapCount = 0;
    public int PierColumnCount = 0;

    // Relation To Children
    public virtual ICollection<Bridge> Bridges { get; private set; }
}
```

**Bridge.cs**:

```
public class Bridge : BasicBaseEntityWithName
{
    public Bridge()
    {
        PierFoundations = new HashSet<PierFoundation>();
    }

    // Fields
    public int ProjectID { set; get; }
    public Project Project { set; get; }

    // Calculated Fields
    public int PierFoundationCount => PierFoundations.Count;
    public int PierCapCount => PierFoundations.Count;
    public int PierColumnCount => PierFoundations.Count;

    // Relation To Children
    public ICollection<PierFoundation> PierFoundations { get; private set; }
}
```

**PierFoundation.cs:**

```
public class PierFoundation : BasicBaseEntityWithName
{
    public PierFoundation()
    {
        PierCaps = new HashSet<PierCap>();
        PierColumns = new HashSet<PierColumn>();
    }

    // Fields
    public float Length { set; get; }

    // Calculated Fields
    public int PierColumnCount => PierColumns.Count;
    public int PierCapCount => PierCaps.Count;
    public float FoundationQty => (Length * Width * Height);

    // Relations To Parents
    public int BridgeID { set; get; }
    public Bridge Bridge { set; get; }

    // Relations To Children
    public ICollection<PierCap> PierCaps { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PierColumn> PierColumns { get; set; }
}
```

**PierColumn.cs:**

```
public class PierColumn : BaseEntityNoName
{
    // Fields
    public float Diameter { set; get; }

    // Relations To Parents
    public int PierFoundationID { set; get; }
    public PierFoundation PierFoundation { set; get; }
}
```

**PierCap.cs:**

```
public class PierCap : BaseEntityNoName
{
    // Fields
    public float CapWidth { set; get; }

    // Relations To Parents
    public int PierFoundationID { set; get; }
    public PierFoundation PierFoundation { set; get; }
}
```

**BaseEntityNoName.cs:**

```
public class BaseEntityNoName
{
    public BaseEntityNoName()
    {
        AddedBy = Core.General.Global.CurrentUseId;
        AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public int AddedBy { get; set; }

    // Becuase they will not appear at new, they will be nullable
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

**BasicBaseEntityWithName.cs:**

```
public class BasicBaseEntityWithName : BaseEntityNoName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Adding to that**, I have this **method** in my **Repository**:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Include(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeExpressions)
{
    DbSet<TEntity> dbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();

    IEnumerable<TEntity> query = null;
    foreach (var includeExpression in includeExpressions)
    {
        query = dbSet.Include(includeExpression);
    }

    return query ?? dbSet;
}
```

**My questions are:**

**Q1**. When I use Include the related entities (PierFoundation, PierCap, PierColumn), I don't get them all!. So, when I type:

```
    PierFoundations = CurrentUnitOfWork.PierFoundationRepository.Include(x => x.PierColumns, x => x.PierCaps);
```

I received just **PierFoundation** and **PierCap**, but not **PierColumn**

**What is the wrong here?**. I want to retrieve all data in the all three of them.

**Q2**. In the **Project** class, I have four calculate fields:

- **BridgeCount** which is solved by **Bridges.Count**
- **PierFoundationCount**
- **PierCapCount**
- **PierColumnCount**

The last three, I don't know how to get them, because they don't have direct relation with **Project**

**BTW:** I am using EF Core 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two issues are unrelated, so answering only the main (as indicated by the post title) **Q1**:

> When I use Include the related entities (PierFoundation, PierCap, PierColumn), I don't get them all!.

It's caused by the following line in your repository method implementation:

```
query = dbSet.Include(includeExpression);
```

As with many LINQ method, it's important to use the `Include` method *return value* when chaining with other calls, and as you can see, this code stores only the *last* `Include` call, hence the behavior you are observing.

It can be fixed by changing the implementation like this:

```
var query = Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
foreach (var includeExpression in includeExpressions)
    query = query.Include(includeExpression); // Note the usage of query variable
return query;
```

or simply

```
return includeExpresions.Aggregate(Context.Set<T>().AsQueryable(), (q, e) => q.Include(e));
```

But note that EF Core uses different approach for including nested data levels  (`ThenInclude`) which cannot be expressed with `Expression<Func<T, object>>`, so you might consider exposing `IQueryable<TEntity>` returning method from your repository and use the EF Core provided `Include` / `ThenInclude` extension methods.

What about **Q2**, consider posting it in a separate SO question (post).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also, I will write another post for the second question. Still, can't understand what do you mean by **exposing IQueryable<TEntity>**

Comment: I meant instead of `public IEnumerable<TEntity> Include(...)` to expose something like `IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll() { return Context.Set<TEntiity>(); }`. In order to allow the caller to use `Include` / `ThenInclude` methods from EF Core.